# Wildfly 10.1 logging in other file

Tags: logging, wildfly

First, sorry for my english.

I have a project (Wildfly 10.1, Java EE). And I need write log from my JMS classes to other log file (MyNewLog.log for example). Now all my logs write in server.log.

I tryed configurate standalone.xml and now my wildfly can create new log file:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:3.0">
    <console-handler name="CONSOLE">
        <level name="INFO"/>
        <formatter>
            <named-formatter name="COLOR-PATTERN"/>
        </formatter>
    </console-handler>
    <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="FILE" autoflush="true">
        <formatter>
            <named-formatter name="PATTERN"/>
        </formatter>
        <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="server.log"/>
        <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
        <append value="true"/>
    </periodic-rotating-file-handler>
    <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="MyNewLog" autoflush="true">
        <formatter>
            <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS}|%-5p|%m%n"/>
        </formatter>
        <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="ChangeCachedAttrsLog.log"/>
        <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
        <append value="true"/>
    </periodic-rotating-file-handler>
    <logger category="com.arjuna">
        <level name="WARN"/>
    </logger>
    <logger category="org.jboss.as.config">
        <level name="DEBUG"/>
    </logger>
    <logger category="sun.rmi">
        <level name="WARN"/>
    </logger>
    <logger category="org.jboss.security.auth.spi" use-parent-handlers="true">
        <level name="ALL"/>
    </logger>
    <logger category="org.jboss.security.auth" use-parent-handlers="true">
        <level name="ALL"/>
    </logger>
    <logger category="org.jboss.security" use-parent-handlers="true">
        <level name="ALL"/>
    </logger>
    <logger category="org.hibernate.SQL" use-parent-handlers="true">
        <level name="ALL"/>
    </logger>
    <logger category="org.hibernate.type" use-parent-handlers="true">
        <level name="TRACE"/>
    </logger>
    <logger category="com.mylog.example" use-parent-handlers="true">
        <level name="ALL"/>
        <handlers>
            <handler name="MyNewLog"/>
        </handlers>
    </logger>
    <root-logger>
        <level name="INFO"/>
        <handlers>
            <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
            <handler name="FILE"/>
        </handlers>
    </root-logger>
    <formatter name="PATTERN">
        <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%e%n"/>
    </formatter>
    <formatter name="COLOR-PATTERN">
        <pattern-formatter pattern="%K{level}%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%e%n"/>
    </formatter>
</subsystem>
```

But how can I tell my java-class write log to this new file?
In code I use slf4j and sl4j:

```
private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyClass.class);
```

Comment: "In code i use slf4j and sl4j" - but that's not working? And MyClass is in com.mylog.example ?

Comment: Is `MyClass.class` in the `com.mylog.example` package? You may also want to set the `use-parent-handlers` to `false` if you don't want those messages in the `server.log`.

Comment: tnx!! it's works!